# Interface and method for DTO and Entity

Tags: java, c#, methods, interface, dto

If I have an entity class

```
public class BarcodeSetting
{
   string Prefix {get;set;}
   string RangeStart {get;set;}
   string RangeEnd {get;set;}
}
```

and a DTO

```
public class BarcodeSettingDTO
{
   string Prefix {get;set;}
   string RangeStart {get;set;}
   string RangeEnd {get;set;}
}
```

1. My question is should I use `BarcodeSettingDTO` in client (winform) ? Or create another class like `BarcodeSettingViewModel`
2. And if I want to have a method `IsBarcodeValid`

```
public bool IsBarcodeValid(BarcodeSettingDTO dto, string barcode)
{
   // return true if barocode is in BarcodeSettingDTO range
   // return false
}
```

Where should I place it (as static a helper method, or put it inside `BarcodeSettingDTO`) ? 
I used to think `IsBarcodeValid` should be a method inside `BarcodeSetting`, but anemic models are not allowed to have any methods.

3. If I have multiple DTOs (in different apps) for one entity. How to reuse some methods? For example, `BarcodeSettingDTO` and `BarcodeSettingAnotherDTO`(which almost like BarcodeSettingDTO). Does that mean I should create `IBarcodeSettingDTO` for the DTOs, and use `IsBarcodeValid (IBarcodeSettingDTO dto, string barcode)`. I searched on google and some people believe DTO should not have any interface. So I'm really confused. What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Dto's are just using for transferring data between tiers, so adding some behavior specifically when it's refer's to validation or business logic is out of its responsibility. Try to concentrate your validation and business rules into business rule validator classes or in rich Entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

**1. My question is should I use BarcodeSettingDTO in client (winform) ? Or create another class like BarcodeSettingViewModel**

==>> It depends. Its always good to decouple and ciew related model objective separately. If you see exactly same attributes/methods in form model and DTO, you may keep it same. But your exposed DTO must not be used as persistent object or should directly interact with persistence layer.

**2. IsBarCodeValid : Where should I place it (as static a helper method, or put it inside BarcodeSettingDTO) ?**

==>> I would advice to creare a Validator helper class for modularity and extensibility

**3. If I have multiple DTOs (in different apps) for one entity. How to reuse some methods?**

==>> Use inheritance principle. Create BarcodeSettingDTO as parent and BarcodeSettingAnotherDTO as child i.e.,

```
BarcodeSettingAnotherDTO extends BarcodeSettingDTO
```

Comment: In Question 3, it still seems to be wired since java or c# is not allowed inherit multiple classes, and if I have multiple methods like `IsBarcodeValid`,  I have no idea what to do without adding more interfaces.

Comment: Can you give a sample usecase for multiple IsBarcodeValid method? You can override/overload the functions for your need.